# Problem I get unwanted things with .replaceall

Tags: javascript

This function is for getting the link for my subcategories. Now the problem is I `console.log()` the values and I have the text "hire/indoor--outdoor-activities" which I don't want to have "--" between "indoor" and "outdoor". But if I remove `.replaceAll` and `.replace` the text is "Indoor & Outdoor Activities". The problem are the two blank spaces between indoor and & and outdoor and &. Is there a regex or something so I can have only one "-"?

```js
const subcategoryLink = (sector) => {
  const sectorLink = `hire/${sector}`
  const lowerCaseLink = sectorLink.toLowerCase().replace('&', '').replaceAll(' ', '-')
  console.log(lowerCaseLink)
  return lowerCaseLink
}

subcategoryLink("Indoor & Outdoor Activities");
```

Comment: What is the expected text you're logging?

Comment: The expected text should be indoor-outdoor-activities

Comment: Oh, so `sectorLink` is `hire/Indoor & Outdoor Activities`, and you want to get that output?

Comment: It's a whole array im rendering with array.map and there several problems other than this one in the text

Comment: I want to get indoor-outdoor-activities i already have the text lowercased and the problem are the blank spaces

Comment: Okay now i got one more problem there is a text  hire/pr- I dont wan't the - after the word how can i fix that

Comment: @StefanTalevski Make sure you're passing in the string 'PR', not 'PR ' with a trailing space.

Comment: I'm not passing the string im getting that from an array I don't understand why - is added after the word beacuse there is no space or word after it

Comment: @StefanTalevski Try logging out the `sector` before formatting it, see what's in there.
To be safe, you can add `.trim()` before the `.toLowerCase()` to remove leading and trailing white space.

Comment: The .trim() before .toLowerCase() helped thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const subcategoryLink = (sector) => {
  const sectorLink = `hire/${sector}`
  const lowerCaseLink =sectorLink.toLowerCase().replace(/\&/g, '').replace('  ',' ').replace(/ /g,'-');

  console.log(lowerCaseLink);

  return lowerCaseLink;
}

subcategoryLink("Indoor & Outdoor Activities");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go ahead and replace any sequence of spaces and '&'s with a single dash using regex

```
sectorLink.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/[ &]+/g, '-')
```

Comment: You can expand this to reducing all "non-word" characters to dashes by using the regex `/\W+/g`, but you should do that replacement before prefixing the path with `hire/`